# How to use NSString's sizeWithFont and drawInRect to workout how much of a string to draw

Tags: iphone, ios, cgcontext, sizewithfont

I'm drawing multiple 'pages' of imagery using a CGContext in the iOS. I've used sizeWithFont and drawInRect combinations extensively in my app. What I need to do is split a large chunk of text across multiple pages. I can size it and work out whether or not it needs another page but how do I know where to chop it? Do I have to do an ugly loop to check word by word until I find a string length that perfectly fits the page and then chop the string at that point? Is there a smarter way?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [NSString additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) to UIKit for drawing text, you can pre-determine the exact amount of space required to render a given text for a given font. If splitting the text into pages, you could use this method.

```
– sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:
```

Assuming the font and line break mode is known, create a CGSize having the same width as your page, and use a sufficiently number for height. This would be the maximum size that we are constraining the text into.

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(pageWidth, 999999999);
CGSize expectedSize = [veryLongString sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:theLineBreakMode];
```

`expectedSize` will tell us the size that the text will take assuming if it could extend vertically infinitely (well close to). To find the number of pages required, just divide the total height by the height of one page.

```
NSInteger totalPages = ceil(expectedSize.height / heightOfOnePage);
```

You would also want to adjust the height of one page to make sure that the last line of text doesn't get clipped. For that to happen, the height of the page should be a multiple of the font's line height. Say the initial page height is `300px`, and the font-height is `16px`, then there will be some clipping as `300/16 = 18.75` which is not a whole number.

```
NSInteger linesWithoutClipping = floor(initialPageHeight / theFont.lineHeight);
CGFloat optimalPageHeight = linesWithoutClipping * theFont.lineHeight;
```

Taking the floor value `18` and multiplying with the font line height `16`, we get an optimal page height of `288` to ensure there's no clipping.

Note that lineHeight was introduced in iOS 4.0, but you could calculate it yourselves if needed for older versions.

Comment: Ok so I can work out how many lines my page size can display. Thats great - thanks for that. Using that figure I can also know at what line to stop rendering on a particular page. The missing piece of the puzzle is how do I where the text got truncated and at what index location I need to start rendering on the next page? Or did I miss that in your answer?

Comment: @Mike - A good point you raised there which I totally missed :). You could skip the part on how to calculate where the next page's text begins altogether. Create a UIScrollView having the same size as of a single page. Add the text label as a subview of this UIScrollView, and to move to the next page, change the contentOffset. For the above example, to go to page 0, set contentOffset to `(0, 0)`. For page 1, use `(0, 288)`, and so on by increasing `y` by multiples of `288`. If the scroll view doesn't render the entire view, then theoretically this should perform fast enough.

Comment: Well, that didn't work too well for me. You might have to rely on Core Text to find out the visible text, especially this function - `CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange`. Splitting word by word, and computing may be a very expensive operation, but worth testing out. Also see the section titled "Columnar Layout" in Core Text [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH4-SW1) which relates to your problem.

Comment: Can I use Core Text with iOS development?

Answer (score 2):

The way I get around this problem is to split by line returns.

```
NSArray * paragraphs = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

You still have to do all the work to determine page breaks and alike but I have found this the best workaround so far.

Comment: How is this a workaround? Why not just let the text print with line breaks naturally?

Comment: I thought the problem was trying to determine where the text finished on one page so you could continue printing on the next page.  By splitting the text into paragraphs, you can calculate if there is enough room to print that single paragraph or if you should create a new page first.  Not perfect but works well.